# how to take a foreach loop timing in powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach, benchmarking

I've a quite complex powershell script, which has to go through a lot of values.
I'd like to know if there is a way to have the timetaken for each value of the loop.
I have an output like that:

```
Severity=INFO  ####################### Work on new Host ################

Severity=INFO  Host found. Trying to Update

Severity=INFO  Ok on DB!

[...]
Severity=INFO  Try to close Session...
```

and I'd like to ad at the end something like this:

```
Severity=INFO it takes $time seconds
```

I've taken a look at "measure-command" and at "Stopwatch", but neither of these seem to fit my needs.

So I was wondering if indeed there is a different way.
Thank you

V.

Comment: take a look at what you can do with `[System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::new()` sometime ... [*grin*]

Comment: I'm struggling with understanding what you might want that neither Measure-Command nor System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch can satisfy.

Comment: *Why* does neither `Stopwatch` or `Measure-Command` fit your needs?  Can you clarify as to what you're looking for that these two functions don't provide?  Also, it would behoove both you and us to [edit] in the details showing the beginning and ending of the loop sections in full.

Answer (score 2):

Define a stopwatch object.

```
$watch = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
```

Put this part inside the loop u would like to measure

```
$watch.Start() #put this at start of the loop

$time = $watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds #this at the end
$watch.reset()
```

Comment: Thank you Rohin, that's exactly what I was looking for. actually, I thought Stopwatch didn't fit my needs just because I didn't know the reset command... thank you again. Really appreciated.